# Different per-computer receive rules with the same name when using an Exchange mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook saves when-receive rules to the Exchange mailbox, including rules marked as "*client-only*" and "*this computer, only*". This causes a problem for same-name rules that use local resources which may be different between computers.

Is there a way to define a "private" when-receive rule in Outlook that does *not* get sync'd with the Exchange mailbox?

Comment: Suggestion: Use a prefix to the name of "private" rules to greatly reduce the chance of a naming conflict. (ie: pvtMailingLists).

Comment: @Steven Thanks, that might be the last resort. An alternative would have been to write some custom code, but it turns out that *reliably* catching new mail events is non-trivial, per [this blog entry](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/).

Comment: When it comes to rules, server-side or client-side doesn't indicate where they are stored, but where they are being processed. Your rules are always stored in your mailbox and since you are using an Exchange account, they are stored in your Exchange mailbox on the server. So client-sides will not work on server but the rules of duplicate names may be unavoidable. You may need to avoid setting the same rule name.